# Neomutt: Macro not working on selected mail in thread but on first mail in thread

Tags: neomutt

I have the following macro (copied directly from ? screen)

```
M1 macro  :set confirmappend=no delete=yes auto_tag=yes\n <copy-message>=jjjjjbbbbbiiiiiooo
+         gi.local/all\n<delete-message>\n<sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-y
+         es\n
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I press M1 on a highlighted email in a thread, the action occurs not on the email I have currently highlighted but on the email that is the original email in the thread.

Would you know what I might be doing wrong? I'm somewhat new to neomutt and don't actually understand the exact syntax of doing things (though I understand what commands are being used here)

Comment: Removed the space before `<copy-message>`. I suspect that space acts to collapse the thread and thus go to the original email and then the original email is acted upon!